# How compile TSX without create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, babeljs

I am building a very basic React app by including the React library script tags in my html page, and loading my components in script tags. I am not using modules or `create-react-app`. My components looks like this:

TIPS.JS

```
class Tips extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I have installed the babel transpolar:

```
npm install babel-cli@6 babel-preset-react-app@3
```

And now I can transpile my JSX component to normal JS with:

```
npx babel --watch src --out-dir . --presets react-app/prod
```

This is fine, but now I want to ALSO compile Typescript TSX, [but these docs are a bit unclear on how to combine these](https://reactjs.org/docs/static-type-checking.html#adding-typescript-to-a-project). They refer to the [Microsoft Typescript React Starter](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter/blob/master/tsconfig.json), but that uses Webpack, so it's not the same setup.

Typescript setup

```
nom install typescript
npx tsc --init
```

TSCONFIG.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "rootDir": "src",
      "outDir": "build"
  },
}
```

Now I should be able to run `npm run build` but I can't find the settings for `package.json`.
Should I use `tsc watch` or `babel watch` ? Or can I just discard babel when using typescript?

In other words, what's the most basic setup to compile TSX components to javascript without using modules and webpack?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can compile Typescript using Babel with `@babel/preset-typescript`.

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-typescript

// .babelrc
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-typescript"]
}
```

So just add this preset & add `tsconfig.json` to your project and you will able to transpile TS.

For [more info](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-typescript)

Comment: Thanks for the hint in the right direction! I just discovered that the `react-app` preset already includes a Typescript option by default, so you don't even need to install the `preset-typescript`. In `.babelrc` you can put `"presets": [["react-app", { "flow": false, "typescript": true }]]`

Comment: Sorry but after adding the typescript preset, my `.ts` files are still ignored. Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Maybe paths issue? Try to specify glob inside `includes` proprty of your tsconfig

Comment: I found it only works when you have additional settings `isTsx:true`, and `extensions:all` in `.babelrc`. It's all very badly documented on the babel site.

Comment: Can you make babel output compile errors?